# Validar fecha y día con función Date()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Saludos !! Necesito que me salga el mensaje en la consola siendo la fecha `13/09` es decir hoy. Como puedo validar esto? Muchas gracias.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">
        <p>Date = {{ today | date }}</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {            
            $scope.today = new Date();
            if (Date()=="13/09") {
                console.log("feliz dia 13/09");
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toma en consideración que los meses en javascript es el número menos uno. Puedes separar los elementos de la fecha y validarlos con tu propio estilo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">
        <p>Date = {{ today | date }}</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {            
            $scope.today = new Date();

            if ($scope.today.getDate()=="13" && $scope.today.getMonth() == "8") {
                console.log("feliz dia 13/09");
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo !!

Comment: De nada estimado. Ha sido un placer poder ayudarle

Answer (score 0):

Es puro Javascript, quizás no te sirve:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
} 

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
if(today == "09/13/2017") {
    // HACER ALGO
}
```

Fuente de casi todo el código: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript

Comment: gracias por tu aporte pero buscaba algo similar en angular :)